# In intelliJ, how to update a existing gist instead of creating a gist?

Tags: github, intellij-idea, gist

In IntelliJ 14, I saw only an action called `Create Gist..`, which will create a new gist every time from a file. However, sometimes I want to reuse an existing gist and keep the commit history. Does anyone have any ideas about how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A gist is just a git repository.  You can clone it and push changes to it like any git repo.  See https://help.github.com/articles/forking-and-cloning-gists/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at plugin called [Get gist (Beta)](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7236?pr=).
Link on [github](https://github.com/johna1203/getGists). I don't use it myself, for now.